# How to ask to continue with employer after an internship?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, career-development, internship

I'm currently working as an intern as a software developer working on a new application for the company. The scope of the project is very large and I have barely scratched the surface in the short time I've been here. I have approximately 1 month before more contract will end.

I'd like to express further interest to my supervisor and ask him if I can remain employed on a part time basis once my internship contract finishes.

What is the best way to go about asking? I don't want to come across too forceful or desperate, and want to ask respectfully without overstepping any boundaries that there might be.

Also, when would be the best time to ask? Right now? Or should I wait until closer to my end date?

Answer (score 7):

Just ask.  Most folks who hire interns see themselves as mentors (and hopefully, behave as such).  It's totally fair game to ask, and they're probably wondering if you're interested, if you're doing well at all.

Answer (score 3):

Now might as well be a good time to ask, given that your manager may need some time to get the paperwork for your part-time work together and that you need to follow up on whatever he promises to do for you.

You might as well for other part-time jobs over the next two weeks. You'll appear somewhat less desperate if you have several irons in the fire.

I was lucky, my boss back then asked me if I was available for part-time work after the summer was over - I smiled like the cat who had just swallowed his owner's canary, I did not even have to ask :)

Yeah, let him know that you are available for part-time work - you may have saved him from having to figure out whom to hire after your internship is over :)